# JavaScript addEventListener to a hidden element

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, hidden

I have this HTML code:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('[uk-toggle]').forEach(function(el) {
  if (el === undefined)
    return false;

  el.addEventListener('click', function() {
    const toggleParams = el.getAttribute('uk-toggle') ? el.getAttribute('uk-toggle').split(';') : '';
    let targetSelector = undefined;

    for (let i = 0; i < toggleParams.length; i++) {
      toggleParams[i] = toggleParams[i].replace(' ', '');
      const paramHash = toggleParams[i].split(':');

      if (paramHash[i] === 'target') targetSelector = paramHash[1];
    }

    document.querySelectorAll(targetSelector).forEach(function(targetElement) {
      if (targetElement.hasAttribute('hidden')) {
        targetElement.setAttribute('hidden', true);
      } else {
        targetElement.removeAttribute('hidden');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<button uk-toggle="target: #product-panel">Product</button>
<section id="product-panel" hidden>
  <div>
    <img uk-toggle="target: #product-info-1" src="...">
    <img uk-toggle="target: #product-info-2" src="...">
    <img uk-toggle="target: #product-info-3" src="...">
  </div>
  <ul id="product-info-1"> ... </ul>
  <ul id="product-info-1" hidden> ... </ul>
  <ul id="product-info-1" hidden> ... </ul>
</section>
```

Now the first case, click on the button is working, but the click on the image is not working.

If I remove the `hidden` property from the `section` everything is working fine.

How can I add event listener to a hidden HTML element? Or what is the problem here?

Comment: Did you try to load the page first, then run js to add 'EventListerners' and add 'hidden' attributes only after that?

Comment: Your code only adds an event listener in one place, and that is where you loop over the `[uk-toggle]` elements. You are not adding anything to the section, whether it be hidden or not. And what the last loop is supposed to achieve, I don’t get either. If an element already has the hidden attribute, you set it again - or remove it if it didn’t have it in the first place …?

Comment: You need event handlers on each image still.